# show a preloader on an HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-video

I am not too sound in javascript, i am doing this assignment, using html5 getUserMedia() api.

so far its working fine as i can take snaps of the frame and draw it on a canvas.

the problem i cant seem to solve now is, to display a preloader at the center of the video when a click on the capture button. i already wrote a delay funtion, which will delay for 2 seconds before capturing the image

i have a function snap

```
 function snapshot(){
 //this function is the one that draws the frame from video to the canvas

 }

 function preloader(){

  //i want the preloader gif image displaying for the 2 seconds on the video

  setTimeout(snapshot, 2000);

 }
```

then i have my event listener as

```
 document.querySelector("#click").addEventListener('click',preloader);
```

i have the gif file (preloader in my image files)

Comment: I dont think that answers it, that is just using html5 video tag, i am using html5 api to get video live from the users webcam

Comment: it's a bit unclear what isn't working. can you use CSS to position and show the preloader, changing the className to hide it after 2 seconds?